# How to zip and unzip png images in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi in my app when i click zip button i need to zip image file and and when i click unzip button i need to unzip file,i tried using below code to zip image but my problem is when i click zip button zip file is creating,but after  that in system using winzip software i try to open file but its not opening its showing "it does not appear to  a valid archive valid file" where i did mistake can u let me how to zip and unzip images

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
Button zip,unzip; 
  String []s=new String[2];   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    zip=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    zip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            s[0]="/sdcard/saved_images/Main.png";    
            //s[1]="/sdcard/Physics_Lab/Stefans_Law/stefan_law.txt"; // path of the second file
            Compress c =new Compress(s,"/sdcard/saved_images/stefen.zip");   
            c.zip();    
        }
    });

    }
  }
    public class Compress { 
      private static final int BUFFER = 80000; 

      private String[] _files; 
        private String _zipFile; 

   public Compress(String[] files, String zipFile) { 
        _files = files; 
     _zipFile = zipFile; 

    } 

   public void zip() { 
    try  { 
     BufferedInputStream origin = null; 
         FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(_zipFile); 

        ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest)); 

  byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER]; 

  for(int i=0; i < _files.length; i++) { 
      Log.d("add:",_files[i]);
    Log.v("Compress", "Adding: " + _files[i]); 
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(_files[i]); 
    origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER); 
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(_files[i].substring(_files[i].lastIndexOf("/") + 1)); 
    out.putNextEntry(entry); 
    int count; 
    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) { 
      out.write(data, 0, count); 
    } 
    origin.close(); 
  } 

  out.close(); 
} catch(Exception e) { 
  e.printStackTrace(); 
} 

   } 

     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out these 2 tutorials to zip and unzip the file

[Android Zip file](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

[Android Unzip file](http://jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

Comment: ok,for zipping i created compress class i just copied all code ,and in zip onclick i didnt chanage code,now also same prblm,i cant able to open created zip file using winzip sofware

Comment: can see once in my zip onclcik code,may be in this code problem i think

Comment: No you must be doing some mistake. I have successfully used this code.

Comment: @Sandeep both links are dead

Answer (score 0):

You can use ZipOutputStream in Java

[See API Document Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html)

You can create the zip file by follow function

```
 OutputStream os = ...
 ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(os));
 try {
     for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) {
         String filename = ...
         byte[] bytes = ...
         ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
         zos.putNextEntry(entry);
         zos.write(bytes);
         zos.closeEntry();
     }
 } finally {
     zos.close();
 }
```

For Open a zip file, you can use ZipInputStream
[Api Document here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html)

```
InputStream is = ...
 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
 try {
     ZipEntry ze;
     while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int count;
         while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
             baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
         }
         String filename = ze.getName();
         byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
         // do something with 'filename' and 'bytes'...
     }
 } finally {
     zis.close();
 }
```

Comment: Actually there are other project for zip and unzip like https://truezip.java.net/
  But I still think the ZipOutputStream is good :D

Comment: ok,but using above code zip file is creating but its not opening

Comment: oh,, Sorry, I tye too fast and make a mistake,, see the edited version

Comment: i tried using below links,i didnt try ur code...but it will  also work..anyway thnkyou JeffLee